# NSData return Null issue

Tags: iphone, sqlite, null, nsdata

In my application I stored multiple `images` in my `database`.
Where my database field type is blob.

Storing the `image` data works well but when i get `image`  `data` from database using below code

```
   NSData *photodata=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStmt, 12) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStmt, 12)];
```

But the field contains null data it returns me <3c3e> in place of null value.
And I inserted data using below query

```
   strQuery_DB = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update tbl_project_review set answer ='%@',comment ='%@',photodata='%@' where prjid=%d",temp,escapedStr1,tempdata,prjid];
```

Comment: `sqlite3` supports parameterised queries, doesn't it?

Comment: When i store null data in blob field it is stored like <> so how can i remove this brackets for null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `%@` specifier with the `stringWithFormat:` method, it invokes the `description` method of the respective argument. For `NSData` objects, this returns a hexadecimal representation of the data surrounded by `<` and `>`. For an empty `NSData` object it will return the string `<>` and this is what is being inserted into the database. This is probably not what you want to do, since this will also double the size of your image data unnecessarily.

You should use parameterised query functions such as `sqlite_bind_blob`. This will make it easier to deal with data input. Basically, you need to change your update query to something like the following (add appropriate error checking, etc):

```
const char sql[] = "update tbl_project_review set answer = ?, comment = ?, photodata = ? where prjid = ?";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, sizeof sql, &stmt, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [tmp UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [escapedStr1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 3, [tempdata bytes], [tempdata length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, prjid);

sqlite3_step(stmt); // check for SQLITE_DONE
```

Answer (score 2):

**Storing image as blob in DB is bad procedure. you need to save image in your cache directory and then you need to save path of image in DB is good.**

Answer (score 0):

bellow is simple code for retrive image from database try..

```
                NSString *imgurl=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 4);
//                NSData *data       = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 4) length:length];
                NSString *imageString=[NSString stringWithCharacters:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 4) length:length];
                UIImage *personImage=[UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
```

i hope this help you...